# Java File Operation- Reading a file whose name we get from the user in console input

Tags: java, file

I have to get the name of a file, say, A.txt from user in console and open the file and read it(to be more specific, tokenize it). How can I do it? I am not able to get the filename from the reader and open it with filename.txt.

Here's the code snippet:

```
    String file = args[0];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Comment: Define "not able". How do you invoke your program? What happens when you run it?

Comment: @JBNizet: I got 'File cannot be resolved to a variable' error.

Comment: @Goalorientedprogrammer: The code you've posted doesn't use the identifier `File`. It would help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, including the full text of the error and indicating which line it refers to.

Comment: I wasn't very sure about the nature of the error. When I changed to BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));. It worked without a hassle. I presume you'll be able to understand now what the issue was. And I have sorted the problem now using try-with-resources technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReadCommandLine {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                BufferedReader br = null;

                try {

                        String sCurrentLine;

                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

                        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                        }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                        try {
                                if (br != null)
                                        br.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

So here your accepting command line argument from args[0] which will be file name that you
will specify in command prompt. Assuming your file and java program are in same folder
and then using bufferedReader your reading the file line by line.

Comment: Thank you @akaElement. Just one more doubt. Where do I place the file in the system which I am trying to open?

Comment: Unless the OP is using Java 6 or earlier, a try-with-resources statement would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @Goalorientedprogrammer you can keep them in same folder with java program in that case you dont have to specify any path. But if your keeping them in other folder then you have to specify that path for example br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));so if you know all of your files are under C: directory then you can take file name at command prompt and concate the file name with path for example br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\"+args[0]));

Comment: @JonSkeet: I changed to try-with-resources. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`args[0]` will refer to the first command line argument, e.g.

```
java Foo filename.txt
```

If you want it on the interactive console, i.e. *after* the program has started, you should use `System.in`, e.g.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String filename = reader.readLine();
```

(As an aside, I'd recommend against using `FileReader` - it always uses the platform default encoding. I'd suggest either using `FileInputStream` wrapped in `InputStreamReader`, or just use [`Files.newBufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-) which defaults to UTF-8 but has an overload to allow you to specify the encoding.)

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. Say I get the file name as 'A' from the user. How do I open it afterwards?

Comment: @Goalorientedprogrammer: Well I've suggested two options - `FileInputStream` or using `Files.newBufferedReader`. It's not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

If your planing to get the user input use

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("file name"+fileName);
```

Please try to get the file name from console. 
Please specify the full path of file if want to get in the BufferedReader.